# Equal sized list items

Tags: css, html, list, border, nav

I am trying to make a navigation bar with list items. I put a border around them and i am trying to figure out how to make the border sizes around the list items equal in size. They always seem to just go with the size of the text inside the border. Sorry if its a dumb question i am new to web design.

```css
#nav {
  background-color: #000;
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  border: 1px outset #c4c4cc;
  background-color: #c4c4cc;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif bold;
  margin-left: 29px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
    <li>Castings</li>
    <li>Machining</li>
    <li>Products</li>
    <li>Home</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add some code and screenshots?

Comment: I tried that and border-width

Comment: Not sure to understand the question, you can use a jsbin or jsfiddler to give us some code, that will help us to help you...  I created one witht he code you add (and delete) http://jsbin.com/onakom/1/edit 
Can you give us more explication about what you are trying to do??

Comment: css    #nav {
 background-color: #000;
 height:100px;
 padding-top: 20px;
}
li {
 display: inline;
 border: 1px outset #c4c4cc;
 
 background-color:#c4c4cc;
 font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif bold;
 margin-left: 29px;
 font-weight:bold;
 padding:12px;
 
 
}
 html      <div id="nav">
<ul>
<li>About Us</li>
<li>Contact Us</li>
<li>Castings</li>
<li> Machining </li>
<li>Products</li>
<li>Home</li>
</ul>


</div>

Comment: Good and what do you want to do exactly?? You want to have each "button" the have exactly the same size??

Comment: `#nav li { width: 200px; }` and remove the `inline`, you want this to be a block element.

Comment: My navigation bar consists of text with borders around them making a rectangle around each of my text. How can I get all the rectangles around my text the same size.

Comment: Should i remove inline even if i want a horizontal Nav?

Comment: And yes forumma Thanks for all your time and help with this

Comment: @JacobYeager - I edited your question. That is what you meant...right?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you are looking for but try this CSS :

```
#nav { 
  background-color: #000; 
  overflow: hidden;
} 

li { 
  float: left;
  background-color:#c4c4cc; 
  font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif bold; 
  margin: 29px; 
  font-weight:bold; 
  padding:12px; 
}

ul {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

The is a js bin with the example : http://jsbin.com/onakom/2/edit

Answer (score 0):

If you want all your list items to be the same width, you need to

1) Set a width on your list item (corresponding to ,say, the widest item)

2) In order to be able to set a width you need to change the display value of your list item from `inline` to `inline-block` because width does not apply to an inline element.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/yL0t743h/3/)**

```css
#nav {
  height: 100px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px outset #c4c4cc;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif bold;
  margin-left: 29px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <ul>
    <li>About Us</li>
    <li>Contact Us</li>
    <li>Castings</li>
    <li>Machining</li>
    <li>Products</li>
    <li>Home</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You just set the height of the `<li>` tag with the value that fits the biggest size of the text in the `<li>` tag. Then it works.